# My image does not display while using mysqli query

Tags: php, image, mysqli

I am working on image, and I want to display only a single image in my site so I did this in my `function.php` file:

```
function image_try(){
        $query_image="SELECT IMG
                      FROM VEG_TECH
                    WHERE IMG='i am a boy.jpg'";
        // Perform database query for total count
        $all_image=mysql_query($query_image);//{$row["id"]}
        confirm_query($all_image);
        return($all_image);
    }
```

and in my `image.php` I did this

```
<?php
include_once('connections/connection.php'); 
    require_once("function.php");
 $about = image_try();
                while($about_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($about)){ ?>
 <img src="images/<?php echo $about_fetch["IMG"]; ?>">
 <?php
}
?>
```

No image is being displayed. I think my query is correct.
Help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Are you sure of src ? In chrome, f12 / network / check red line.
That can be space in name, wrong basehref , ...

Comment: all you need to do is inspect the html produced using the browser inspection tools

Answer (score 0):

Your image is with spaces.

Use this :

```
echo str_replace(' ', '%20', $about_fetch["IMG"]);
```

Comment: no nothing displays. Should i use something check if there is an error!!

Comment: yes the path is correct..!!!i just thought!!in this image, the name is with spaces.. i am a boy.jpg. Does that matters.